# Move Between different Navigation Controllers in Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I want to move from one UINavigatioController to other UINavigatioController. Scenario is First I am at ContactVC and after pressing any cell I will be move to ChatVC. Now when I press the back button on chatVC I want to move back on InboxVC. How can I achieve this scenario.

[image: select contact in contact list and move to chat VC and in chatVC, on pressing back button which shows in navigation bar I move to inbox VC]

Comment: This "feels" like convoluted logic. Why use **two** navigation controllers? If you can *combine* the navigation into **one** (using a presentation view controller where needed), then why confuse users? Please, consider refactoring what you are trying to do!

Comment: i am using two navigation controllers because i am using a tab bar controller. so every tab bar item maintain its navigation

Answer (score 0):

A `UINavigationController` is a stack based navigation system. This means when you navigate forwards you simply add another `UIViewController` to the stack, and when you navigate backwards you pop a `UIViewContrller` off the stack.

To do what you are proposing you will need to change the underlying `UIViewController`'s that are currently in the navigation stack. You can do this by using `func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController], animated: Bool)` on `UINavigationController` programatically, but you can't do it through a storyboard as thats not how a `UINavigationController` is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` controller keeps a stack of the views (in simple words to understand) when a push a new view controller onto it. So when you press back it essentially pops the last view controller to display its parent controller. This is also normal user behaviour on the iOS platform.

The behaviour you are looking in counter-intuitive to the user since you are breaking their flow of navigation. But if you can a have a strong case for it. You can manually create a back button which can push to the inbox controller to get this sort of behaviour in code or in interface builder.

---

Another way to achieve this perhaps what you can see in other apps is:

1. you have a Signup view controller (which might be the form). When the signup is completed.
2. change the root view controller of the window to Inbox controller and
3. The same time, push the Chat controller so when your user pushes the back button, they will be taken back to the Inbox.